# Bootstrap - How get small video thumbnail?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I would like to have a small thumbnail of a video, uploaded by user in a HTML webpage. When user clicks on it, it shows the video in the same webpage.

I tried this code:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="/video/hanson.mp4"></iframe>
</div>
```

But it is not what I need.

Please note that the videos are not on youtube or so on. And there are numerous video files so the function should be able to create thumbnail from the address of the file on the server.

Is there any way to get thumbnail as I described?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, if several video formats (not the file extension but the content of the video) will be uploaded then the video cannot be played on all devices. For example, Apple is very strict in what will play and what will not play. About your question, this must be done on the server with php or asp (depending what you are using). It is difficult to pick a frame of the video, maybe it is a screenshot of a black frame at that moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example this will work with thumbnails in Bootstrap.

Update: Set image src to https

```js
function play(item){
  var videoFiles = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/';
  var videoParam = 'autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1';
  document.getElementById('player').src = videoFiles + item + '?' + videoParam;
}
```

```html
<!-- bootstrap -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex flex-wrap mx-auto" style="width:100%; max-width:400px;">

<div class="col-12 mb-4 player">
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <!-- first item of playlist -->
    <iframe id="player" class="embed-responsive-item" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1G4isv_Fylg?version=3&autoplay=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1"
    allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div><!--/.player-->

<div class="col-12 text-center playlist">
  <div class="row">
    <a class="col-3 mb-3" onClick="play('1G4isv_Fylg')" href="javascript:void(0)">
      <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/1G4isv_Fylg/0.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="card-body py-2"><small>Paradise</small></div>
    </a>
    <a class="col-3 mb-3" onClick="play('YlUKcNNmywk')" href="javascript:void(0)">
      <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/YlUKcNNmywk/0.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="py-2"><small>Californication</small></div>
    </a>
    <a class="col-3 mb-3" onClick="play('xik-y0xlpZ0')" href="javascript:void(0)">
      <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/xik-y0xlpZ0/0.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="py-2"><small>A Forest</small></div>
    </a>
    <a class="col-3 mb-3" onClick="play('1w7OgIMMRc4')" href="javascript:void(0)">
      <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/1w7OgIMMRc4/0.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="py-2"><small>Sweet Child Mine</small></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div><!--/.playlist-->

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But the video is not on youtube, so the thumbnails are not prepared beforehand. I edited the question. Maybe it is more to the point.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to add one thumbnail add click event also, I implemented this. look into it,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#video-id,.demo-play-btn').click(function(){ 
    $('#video-id').get(0).paused ? $('#video-id').get(0).play() : $('#video-id').get(0).pause(); 
    $(".demo-play-btn").toggle();
  }); 
});
```

```css
.demo-play-btn{
  position:absolute;
  top:35%;
  background:#fff;
  left:35%;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.demo-play-btn img{
  width:50px;
}
```

```html
   

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="demo-video">
      <video id="video-id" width="470" height="255" poster="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5Peo-ivmupE/maxresdefault.jpg">
         <source src="https://st2.depositphotos.com/4083751/6003/v/600/depositphotos_60037637-stock-video-toddler-with-bottle-and-dummy.mp4" type="video/mp4">        
       </video>
       <div class="demo-play-btn">
           <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/9Oa4tg5B3DLeqAIsO_qRhmQg_pqtW3RtwBQJYdcv4e44lGfl4UReTpWpe5TDjlyJU3254RakFD48FPfsALnBI2cD6wxt8zMRNtrGEytVkMDHfLxBdiOG7JU-m0csf5RC6AY" class="play-btn" title="Play Video">
       </div>
 </div>
```